# Showing that a Hilbert Basis $(e_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ verifies $u= \sum (u,e_n)e_n $

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

The definition I have been given for a **Hilbert Basis** in a Hilbert Space $H$ over $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ is:

> A sequence $(e_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is an orthonormal basis if it
>   verifies:
>
> - $|e_n|=1$ and $(e_n,e_m)=0$ for $n \neq m$.
> - The linear space spanned by the $e_n$'s is dense in H.

Now I want to show that  for every $ u \in H$  we have $u=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(u,e_n)e_n$.

I understand I have to use projections,considering we have that H is the Hilbert sum of $E_n=\mathbb{K}e_n$, then show that $P_{E_n}u=(u,e_n)e_n$ and finally that $u=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P_{E_n}u$.

I need help showing that  $u=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P_{E_n}u$.

$(·,·)$ denotes scalar product and $P_{E_n}u$ denotes projection onto $E_n$ of u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to show is that, for any fixed $N$, the following holds for all choices of scalars $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots,\alpha_N$:
$$
    \left\|u-\sum_{n=1}^{N}(u,e_n)e_n\right\| \le \left\|u-\sum_{n=1}^{N}\alpha_n e_n\right\|
$$
Therefore, for all $M \ge N$,
$$
        \left\|u-\sum_{n=1}^{M}(u,e_n)e_n\right\| \le \left\|u-\sum_{n=1}^{N}(u,e_n)e_n\right\|.
$$
Now assume that $u$ is in the closure of the linear span of $\{ e_n \}$, and let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Then there must exist $\sum_{n=1}^{N}\alpha_n e_n$ such that
$$
    \left\|u-\sum_{n=1}^{N}\alpha_n e_n\right\| < \epsilon.
$$
Hence, there exists $N$ such that
$$
          \left\|u-\sum_{n=1}^{M}(u,e_n) e_n\right\| < \epsilon,\;\;\; M \ge N.
$$
The conclusion is that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(u,e_n)e_n$ converges to $u$.

**Note:** These arguments do not require a complete inner product space. The assumption that $u$ is in the closure of the linear span of $\{ e_n \}$ is enough to force the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(u,e_n)e_n$ to $u$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really get the idea. Why do I need to show the first inequality? And also I don't know how to obtain the second inequality from the first one.

Comment: @D1X : The first inequality is the definition of closest point projection, which is the same as orthogonal projection on finite-dimensional inner product spaces. The first inequality implies the second. Why? Because one specific chose of constants $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots,\alpha_N,\alpha_{N+1},\cdots,\alpha_{M}$ is $(u,e_1),(u,e_2),\cdots,(u,e_N),0,0,\cdots 0$.

Comment: Thanks TrialAndError. Now I get it.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(u,e_n)e_n$ converges?

$u-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(u,e_n)e_n$ is orthogonal to every $e_k$?

Comment: 1) Yes, it does in $\overline{span((e_n))}$, as the sequence $y_N= \sum_{n=1}^{N} (u,e_n)e_n \in span((e_n))$